# Как изменить директорию куда сохраняет файлы функции media_handle_sideload в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется такой код в котором создается пост с пользовательским типом: `myphoto`, из сети качается изображение и сохраняется в качестве миниатюры для этого поста:

```
// данные нового поста типа: myphoto
$_post_data = array(
  'post_title' => $title,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'post_type' => 'myphoto',
);
// создаем пост
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $_post_data );

// скачиваем файл 
$tmp_file = download_url( $url );

// загружаем файл в медиатеку WordPress
$att_id = media_handle_sideload( array(
  'name' => $title,
  'tmp_name' => $tmp_file,
), $post_id, $title );

// устанавливаем миниатюру для записи
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $att_id);
```

Как поменять папку куда сохраняется через `media_handle_sideload` файл изображения? Например, я хочу чтобы папка имела название в виде ID поста (`$post_id` в моём примере)?

Answer (score 0):

Google-поиск и эксперименты привели к такому "костыльному" решению:

```
// данные нового поста типа: myphoto
$_post_data = array(
  'post_title' => $title,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'post_type' => 'myphoto',
);
// создаем пост
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $_post_data );

// скачиваем файл 
$tmp_file = download_url( $url );

$_REQUEST['post_id'] = $post_id;

// загружаем файл в медиатеку WordPress
$att_id = media_handle_sideload( array(
  'name' => $title,
  'tmp_name' => $tmp_file,
), $post_id, $title );

unset($_REQUEST['post_id']);

// устанавливаем миниатюру для записи
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $att_id);


add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'filter_upload_dir' );
function filter_upload_dir($args)
{
  if ( get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) == "yd_photo" ) {
      $mydir         = "/{$_REQUEST['post_id']}";
      $args['path'] = $args['basedir'] . $mydir;
      $args['url']  = $args['baseurl'] . $mydir;
  }
  return $args;
}
```